# Link Javascript file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been working on this for the past several weeks, and I am still right where I started. I finally found a chunk of server code that linked a javascript file (in the same location as my javascript file):

```
<?php
    OCP\Util::addscript('core', 'visitortimezone');
?>
```

So, I linked my file like this:

```
<?php
    OCP\Util::addscript('core', 'myJavascript');
?>
```

But it still isn't working. My javascript, HTML, and CSS all worked perfectly in my Jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/khenckel/963m7tzc/). I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Could there be an issue linking because I am using PHP, or because the file is Jquery instead of pure Javascript?

Comment: Can you post the final html rendered in the browser?If the myJavascript code is Jquery  you should add Jquery library before myJavascript .

Comment: Are you including `Jquery library` in your application?

Comment: Yes, I am using Jquery (that is probably my issue). I just tried referencing the library like this:

    OC_Util::addScript("jquery-1.10.0.min");
    OC_Util::addScript("jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min");
    OC_Util::addScript("jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom");

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: should work if you reference jquery in your js file

Comment: This question is incomplete. What is `OCP\Util` class? Where are you using this? My guess is that it's an OwnCloud installation, so why don't you tell this to us?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

or

```
?> <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script> <?php
```